# API Authentication for Azure Form Recognizer

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

For API authentication, I understand that Azure Form Recognizer uses "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" which is the Azure Subscription ID. Also, shouldn't there be an API key as well, which we should be using for accessing any API across the subscription? Or is it there?
Also, once the authentication is successful, do we have a kind of token which ensure the user remains authenticated for some time? How does this work?
Moreover, as per the attached image, there are two API keys involved while using the AFR APIs. What is the use of those two keys?

[image: AFR API issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, we use key1 or key2 as `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` as below :

[image]
[image]

If you want to use the Azure AD access token to call this API, see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/authentication?tabs=powershell#authenticate-with-azure-active-directory).

Comment: But consider an application which I am building to access the AFR through its APIs. In that case there should be a mechanism for me to authenticate against AD first, using oAuth, get a session token and then access the API. Without the token, I wont be able to access the API. But the concept of token based authorization is not mentioned anywhere in the AFR API docs. Please help.

Comment: Using API just having the API keys do not make sense. If I share the API key with my friend, will he be able to use it in his application?

Comment: @Sachindra Yes, it is not secure to use keys. See this doc to get access tokens to call the API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/authentication?tabs=powershell#authenticate-with-azure-active-directory

Comment: @Sachindra, how's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Comment: Thank You Stanley. Its resolved and clear. :)